# How do i plot $(r−2)^2 + z^2 \leq 1$?

Tags: graphing-functions

How can I plot this equation in 3D? Given in cylindrical coordinates. Have tried in wolfram but couldn't work it out..

$$(r−2)^2 + z^2 \leq1$$

Comment: Could you specify your question more clearly? As it's formulated, you have the equation of a circle with Center at (2,0) and radius 1.

Comment: He is working in cylindrical coordinates, not cartesian ones. Plus, it would be a disk rather than a circle. @Luke

Comment: Whoops, overlooked that, sorry. Still it nearly solves his problem.

Comment: It depends on what you consider to be near the solution I would say, to me it is the very beginning. ;) @Luke

Answer (score 0):

You draw a solid disk with radius $1$ at $(x,y,z)=(2,0,0)$ then rotate it a full $2\pi$ radian with respect to $z$ axis.

A solid donut

Answer (score 0):

Parametrize the surface of  $$(r−2)^2 + z^2 \leq1$$ as $$r=2\pm \cos(\theta), z=\pm \sin(\theta)$$

for $$0\le \theta \le 2\pi$$

You get a donut shaped solid with the inner radius of one and outer radius of three where $z$ runs from $-1$ to $1$.

Comment: Thanks! Most useful! Now it's solved